# asp.net mvc automapping view model to domain model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

Is it possible to automap UserViewModel to User?

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}


public class UserViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    public List<Role> AvailableRoles { get; set; }
    public List<Role> AssignedRoles { get; set; }

    public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
    public int[] AssignedSelected { get; set; }
    public string SavedAssigned { get; set; }
}   

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UserViewModel, User>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(model, user);
```

I've tried this, but it won't work. I need it for my Edit action method in the User controller to save the changes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UserViewModel, User>()    
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User));
```